# Why is my GLSL version so low?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a XFX 7850 (fairly new card), and just switched to linux. For some reason, when I print my GLSL version out, I only have 1.3. Is this just an issue with the default Linux drivers? Are the drivers just generic so they support most cards out of the box? And if I install the AMD Catalyst drivers, will I have a higher version?

Comment: It is impossible to say. Mesa may be to blame, I would suggest you investigate the ***other*** strings (`GL_VERSION`, `GL_RENDERER`, `GL_VENDOR`). If you are using the proprietary drivers from AMD these other strings will make that immediately apparent. The GLSL version is also not limited to a single string, if you run through `glGetStringi (i, GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)` for each `i` < `GL_NUM_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSIONS`, you will get the complete list of versions your GLSL compiler supports.

Comment: It seems I have 2.1 Mesa 9.2.1. Is Mesa the driver? I'm also guessing 2.1 is the OpenGL version...

Comment: @opiop65: can you post the result of the following command in your question: `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

Comment: @opiop65: Not exactly, Mesa is more like a front-end. Intel's "official" drivers work with it, but if you want the latest hardware path on NV/AMD hardware you need to use the proprietary drivers from those vendors. In the case of AMD, their proprietary driver is called `fglrx`. That said, even using the open source implementation for your system if you had the latest version of Mesa installed on your system, would (mostly) support up to GLSL 3.30.

Comment: That was a gross misuse of the *"Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic ..."* close flag. The question is not immediately worded in such a way that it appears to be about software development, but this is ***very much*** an issue that, if not addressed, prevents developing software for OpenGL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And if I install the AMD Catalyst drivers, will I have a higher version

Yes, the Linux Catalyst currently implements at max GL 4.3 and GLSL 430. The open-source radeon driver that comes as part of the Xorg driver stack, is currently stuck at GL 3.1 and GLSL 1.40 or, depending on your distribution, you're even stuck with the LLVM softipe at GL 2.1 and GLSL 1.30 - at least on Ubuntu 13.10 with a bleeding edge Xorg from the xorg-edgers PPA.

For a reference on the open-source radeon driver, check [this](http://wiki.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#1) out.

Comment: Updating to the latest AMD beta drivers fixed the issue!

Comment: Please don't spread misinformation. Mesa also contains the OpenGL drivers (aka state trackers) for the DRI/DRM graphics infrastructure.

Comment: @datenwolf: Sorry about that. Removed. Will research it better and update accordingly.